# How to install the latest emscripten on Ubuntu using command line?

Tags: updates

I want to install the latest emscripten in ubuntu for playing with WebAssembly using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install emscripten
```

But it gives me the version 1.22.1 which is a version in 2014 and do not support WebAssembly compiling.

```
$ emcc --version
emcc (Emscripten GCC-like replacement) 1.22.1 ()
Copyright (C) 2014 the Emscripten authors (see AUTHORS.txt)
This is free and open source software under the MIT license.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Are there a simple guide for installing the latest emscripten in command line?

Comment: UPDATE 2022: `sudo apt-get install emscripten` works for me

Answer (score 8):

The installation instructions suggest: download [emsdk-portable.tar.gz](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mozilla-games/emscripten/releases/emsdk-portable.tar.gz)

Unzip it, then open a terminal and run:

```
# Fetch the latest registry of available tools.
./emsdk update

# Download and install the latest SDK tools.
./emsdk install latest

# Make the "latest" SDK "active"
./emsdk activate latest
```

see: http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#installation-instructions for more information

Comment: This doesn't seem to install emcc.

Answer (score 7):

From the emscripten's doc page [ *from the ground zero* ]

**1. Get the emsdk repo**

```
git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git
```

**2. Enter that directory**

```
cd emsdk
```

**3. Download and install the latest SDK tools**

```
./emsdk install latest
```

**4. Make the "latest" SDK "active"**

```
./emsdk activate latest
```

**5. Activate PATH and other environment variables**

```
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

> these variables are set for the current terminal, if you want to make it for everybody, so you can put into any terminal profile. Here they are:

The environment variables:

EMSDK = < path to emsdk dir >

EM_CONFIG = ~/.emscripten

EMSDK_NODE = < path to emsdk dir >/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node

**6. Now just try it!**

```
emcc
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not enough to build a newer version of emscripten. You will also have to build LLVM yourself, as emscripten will complain about

```
CRITICAL:root:WebAssembly set as target, but LLVM has not been built with the WebAssembly backend
```

I got it running by following the tutorial on building LLVM at
http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html and some hints from
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/New-WebAssembly-Backend

```
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
git -C llvm/tools clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git
git -C llvm/projects clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git
git -C llvm/projects clone http://llvm.org/git/openmp.git
git -C llvm/projects clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxx.git
git -C llvm/projects clone http://llvm.org/git/libcxxabi.git
mkdir llvmbuild
cd llvmbuild
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="llvm/tools/clang;llvm/projects/libcxx;llvm/projects/libcxxabi" \
      -DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=WebAssembly \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      ../llvm
make all
cd ..
```

And then following the tutorial on building emscripten at http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/

```
git clone https://github.com/juj/emsdk.git
cd emsdk
./emsdk install sdk-incoming-64bit binaryen-master-64bit
./emsdk activate sdk-incoming-64bit binaryen-master-64bit
source ./emsdk_env.sh
cd ..

# configure emscripten to use self-built LLVM
cat ~/.emscripten \
    | sed "s:LLVM_ROOT=[^\n]*:LLVM_ROOT='${PWD}/llvmbuild/bin':g" \
    > ~/.emscripten.tmp
mv ~/.emscripten ~/.emscripten.bak
mv ~/.emscripten.tmp ~/.emscripten
```

Comment: After that, I could compile a .cpp file to WebAssembly as described at http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/ . Notice that the html file uses XmlHttpRequests, so it doesn't work through the file:// protocol, you have to load it via http:// or https://